# how to go one view to another view?

Tags: iphone

I create one Application for Language Display. Now, I need to display the Another Page when I tapped on first button then go to Another Page. If I tapped on Second Button, It will back on first Page.

How to code it?

Thanks in Advance...

Rahul Rana

Comment: go and study the basics of iPhone before asking these silly questions

Comment: If you don't know why use your to see this silly question

Comment: Shant gadadhari bheem....Shant

Comment: Rahul, the way to learn iPhone programming is *not* to come to stackoverflow and ask every question that comes into your head as soon as it comes into your head. You need to put in some effort to learn the basics, and then ask more specific questions if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the first page, instantiate a UINavigationController, and when the AnotherPage is tapped, push the second page onto the NavigationController stack.

Comment: Is it require take one ViewController?

Comment: Yes, what you want to do is this: create a UINavigationController with your first VC as it's root.  Add the NavigationController's view to your application window.  In your first VC, when user taps "Second", push the second VC onto the NavController stack.

Comment: hi, I create a UINavigationController and try tapped with second VC it not done]

Comment: Either post some code, or start with a working example and modify it to do what you need.